# Tortoise and hare algorithms

Tags: ds.algorithms, soft-question

Consider the problem:
Given an array $a[0..n]$ where $n\ge 1$ and $a[i]\in [n]$ for all $i=0,\ldots,n$ find two indices $s\neq t$ so that $a[s] = a[t]$.

This problem has a *stunning* solution running in $O(n)$ time and using 2 words of space only, attributed to Bob Floyd (at least by Knuth). The crux is to see this as a cycle finding problem (even though there is zero mention of a cycle let alone a graph), and employ the so called Tortoise and Hare algorithm (again, by Floyd).

This Tortoise and Hare algorithm was later used by Pollard in his factoring algorithm and somewhat recently extended [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.3690) to solve the element distinctness problem using small space.

What are some other uses of this algorithm or extensions of it in TCS?

Comment: Pollard used for dlog. Do you have references for factoring?

Comment: @Turbo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm

Comment: Maybe not in TCS, but it can be used to find collisions in Hash Functions with $O(2^{n/2})$ time and just a bit of memory.